# How do I enable credit card autofill feature outside U.S. and Canada?

Tags: firefox, auto-form-fill

At the moment of writing, “The credit card autofill feature is available in the U.S. since Firefox version 81 and in Canada since Firefox version 86. This feature is not currently available for Firefox users outside of the U.S. and Canada.” ([source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/credit-card-autofill))

This makes it very painful to use Firefox as soon as I want to pay online—as you may guess, I'm not from U.S. or Canada—more specifically, I live in France. Usually, I just switch to Chrome when I need to pay, which makes the flow much more complex than it needs to be.

How do I trick Firefox into thinking I'm living in the U.S.? Or is there any other option to force the credit card autofill feature?

Comment: You'll probably find that even if you manage to fool the system into auto-filling, it will then think you're in the wrong country for your card. You don't say what platform you're on, but Safari has had this feature pretty much world-wide for about a decade [& these days with far safer alternatives than giving all & sundry your CC details]

Comment: @Tetsujin: well, switching back and forth between Firefox and Safari is not much different than doing it with Firefox and Chrome—the idea was to make Firefox do autocompletion, not to find a different browser that already does. And to answer your question, I'm using Debian.

Comment: I wasn't really suggesting switching back & forth, I was suggesting abandoning Firefox ;) [You couldn't pay me to use Chrome; of all the major browsers, why use one whose entire business plan is based around selling your habits to others?] As you're on Debian, I doubt you have much choice, though.

Comment: Try in `about:config` to set `extensions.formautofill.available = on` and `extensions.formautofill.creditCards.available = true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to `about:config` and:

- Change `extensions.formautofill.creditCards.available`to `true`
- Change `extensions.formautofill.creditCards.enabled` to `true`
- Add your country code at the end of the list in `extensions.formautofill.creditCards.supportedCountries`. E.g. I'm in Argentina, so I added **AR** to the list: `US,CA,GB,FR,DE,AR`.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open `about:config` in Firefox by entering it in the URL search bar.
2. Once you're in the configuration menu search for the following keys and change their values to match the following:

> extensions.formautofill.creditCards.supported: **on**

> extensions.formautofill.creditCards.enabled: **true**

> extensions.formautofill.creditCards.supportedCountries: **(add your
> country ISO code to the list of pre-existing countries)**

See in the [Mozilla's Wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Features/Form_Autofill) for a further explanation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).